# Why can't Capybara find an element with selenium_chrome_headless but it can with selenium_chrome?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, capybara

I have a very simple integration test

```
visit root_path
click_link 'Sign In' # <--
```

which works with

```
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome
```

but fails with

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find visible link "Sign In"
```

when using

```
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless # headless fails
```

And that is with

```
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10
```

And I have also tried

```
click_link 'Sign In', wait: 30
```

and

```
sleep 10
click_link 'Sign In'
```

**version details**

At the time of this writing I have the latest versions of [capybara](https://rubygems.org/gems/capybara/versions) and [selenium-webdriver](https://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver/versions):

```
-bash> gem list | grep capybara
capybara (3.34.0, 3.18.0)

-bash> gem list | grep selenium
selenium-webdriver (3.142.7, 3.142.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The default "headless" viewport is narrower than the "head" one, so the 'Sign In' link you're trying to click may be hidden beneath a "hamburger menu icon":

[image]

Thus, first click the burger:

```
visit root_path
find('#burger').click if Capybara.current_driver == :selenium_chrome_headless
click_link 'Sign In'
```

I figured this out by capturing a screenshot prior to trying to click the 'Sign In' link:

```
visit root_path
save_and_open_screenshot
click_link 'Sign In'
```

As an alternative, rather than check `current_driver`, you could instead check the window width as compared to the width at which the burger appears:

```
find('#burger').click if page.current_window.size[0] < 900
```